# Chart the TIME something happened on a series of DATES

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two columns of data.

Column 1 is the **DATE** (i.e. 1/5/2011 )

Column 2 is the **TIME** a thing happened on that **DATE** (i.e. 16:42 )

I need the **DATE** to be on the **X** axis and the **TIME** to be on the **Y** axis.

It seems if I use a Line chart Excel will stop the **DATE** series after only 10 dates, despite me selecting a years worth of **DATES**.

If this is a common issue I can't seem to locate the answer.

The goal is to visualize if the **TIME** a thing happens on the **DATE** and to determine if the **TIME** that this is happening occurring later in the day.

Comment: Why do you use "Line Graph"? If you have several data on a day with different time, "Dot Graph" is suitable.

Comment: Sorry I just edited it to be more clear. There is only ever one TIME on any given DATE.

Comment: Did you try to make Line graph of TIME without DATE? That graph has TIME in Y axis and series in X axis. If you satisfy that line graph, try to use DATE as data-title of X axis. By following these two step, you may be able to find what cause the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a graph that looked like this:[image: Line Graph of Date and Time]

by adding a series like this:

[image: Modifying the series for each column]

Nothing too fancy, just formatted the column to have a max of 1 (1 day = 24hrs)

Comment: It turns out some of my TIME data also contained DATE data, although it was hidden due to formatting. This answer did set me on the right path to discovering why my Y axis was giving me trouble. Thanks!